# Deobfuscating big files

Tags: deobfuscation, javascript

I'm trying to deobfuscate JS file, but it's to big for online services, like deobfuscate.io. I just can't copy content of file, because it have ~4M symbols. All deobfuscate services proccess file in browser, so my PC is just hangs. How can i deobfuscate such a big file?

Answer (score 0):

Many of the online js deobfuscators are actually open source like [d4js](https://github.com/lelinhtinh/de4js) and [deobfuscator.io](https://github.com/ben-sb/javascript-deobfuscator). They also have instructions on how to run them locally, thus the runtime will depend on your resources and neither depend on the browsers memory limitations neither on the server's (depending on whether they run locally or remotely).

P.S. The above mentioned beobfuscators run on the client side, so if running them out of the browser doesn't make a big difference you probably have to increase your resources.